# how to use the same label twice

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

So I have a label that will be updated every few seconds. I want to display this label twice, one in a window and the other one in a different window. I want it so that when the function runs, it will affect both. How can I achieve this without changing anything in the function? Thanks in advance.

I am sorry for not providing an example, so I made a simple example on what I mean.

```
x = 0
def change():
    global myLabel

    myLabel.config(text=x)
    x += 1


firstWindow = Tk()

myLabel = Label(firstWindow, text="0")
myLabel.pack(padx=5)



secondWindow = Toplevel()

# second myLabel here

myButton = Button(secondWindow, text="Add 1", command=change)
myButton.pack()

mainloop()
```

Comment: You can assign it to a variable and reference it in the label. Please provide a [mre]

Comment: a simple solution I can think of is just using the same `textvariable` (tho I don't know how it affects different windows, but You can give it a try)

Comment: @Matiiss As long as the 2 windows have a common `Tk` parent using `StringVar` should be fine (like in this case).

Comment: @TheLizzard: Actually, setting `textvariable=` to an `IntVar` works too, and is more convenient in this case.

Comment: @martineau Didn't properly read OP's code :D. My bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think what you want to do is possible because, as far as I know, a `tkinter` widget can only be associated with one window, However you ***can*** define two `Label`s that display the same `tkinter` variable (and also define multiple `Button`s to update it as well, if you wish).

Here's what I mean:

```
from tkinter import *


firstWindow = Tk()

x = IntVar(value=0)

def change():
    x.set(x.get()+1)

myLabel1 = Label(firstWindow, textvariable=x)
myLabel1.pack(padx=5)

myButton1 = Button(firstWindow, text="Add 1", command=change)
myButton1.pack()

secondWindow = Toplevel(firstWindow)

myLabel2 = Label(secondWindow, textvariable=x)
myLabel2.pack(padx=5)

myButton2 = Button(secondWindow, text="Add 1", command=change)
myButton2.pack()

mainloop()
```

Comment: Not really important in this case but it wouldn't be a bad idea to pass in `firstWindow` when creating the `Toplevel()`.

Comment: @TheLizzard: Not strictly necessary, but it's better to be explicit—thanks.